# How does a movie downloader app work in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video-streaming

How can a video downloader app work in iOS? There are many apps like

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/video-downloader-super-lite/id481701140?mt=8

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/video-downloader/id524931696?mt=8

How they get the URL from the video Player (video from Web View)? I tried with a proxy but was unable to trace.

Answer (score 3):

They parse the response directly to find the URL for the video, then they download the video data and convert it if necessary.

In some cases it's easy (if the URL is directly a video). In others it's a little more complicated. Support for common video hosting sites like youtube, vimeo, ted etc. is hardcoded. Each site has a specific scheme to represent the video page (which is html, possibly with javascript). Knowledge of that scheme allows to recognize it and find the link to the data.

In some cases the video is in a directly usable format (like h264). In others it's not. In many cases what you get from the html page is the URL of a flash file. Next step is to download the flash file itself and parse it to either extract the video or the URL to the video data.

In other cases the video is not served as a file at all. It may use a streaming protocol, for example. Once obtained the parameters and URL for the stream, the stream must be received and the video converted to a video file locally.